# What type of subsoil root structure provides better plant anchorage?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

Which type of root is better for good anchorage for small plants: tap roots or fibrous roots?. How about for trees:  tap root or a fibrous system?

Comment: This is partially dependent on soil texture/types